# Sql: Correlated subqueries in where clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve this question from sqlzoo:

> 7: Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area.

I did find the answers myself by using join. But below is an alternative:

```
SELECT continent, name, area 
FROM world x
WHERE area >= ALL(SELECT area 
                  FROM world y
                  WHERE y.continent = x.continent
                    AND area > 0)
```

Normally, the subquery will return a list of "area" value so `>= all(subquery)` means "larger or equal to the max value of the list", say for all of the continents.

However, the final results return the maximum values for each continents

1. How can it be like that?
2. What is the role of `and area>0` in the subquery?

Comment: add some subset of data

Comment: Perhaps there are some places which have an area of 0.

Comment: It returns the maximum value for each of the continents because a correlated query is used: `WHERE y.continent = x.continent`